# Ajax returning 500 error in laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Laravel 5.2 - new application

Ive only just got back into laravel, and im having trouble with an ajax post.

Basically when you reorder the list its calling ajax to change the order and save it in the database. ive been researching around but none seem to be helping me..

What i have so far....

html/blade.php code:

```
<ul class="sortable">
    @foreach ($pages as $page)
        <li class="ui-state-default" data-id="{{ $page->id }}">{{ $page->name }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Ajax

```
$(function() {
    $('.sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function(e, ui) {

        var id = $('ul.sortable li').map(function(){
            return $(this).data("id");
        }).get();

            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/abc',
                data: {
                    id: id, 
                    _token: token
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Error:', data);
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });


        });
    });
```

Routes.php

```
Route::post('abc', 'HomeController@SomeFunction');
```

Controller

```
public function SomeFunction(Request $request){


    $id = $request->input('id');

    $i = 1;

    foreach($id as $val) {

        $page = Page::where('id', (int)$val)->first();

        $page->order = $i;
        $page->save();

        $i++;

    }


}
```

UPDATE:

Thank you for all the support from everyone above i have put all the suggestions that people helped me code better and solve the issue... I also found out that when i convert the $val to an int it was updating in the database. thank you

Comment: I'd guess it is because $request is undefined but you really, really, really should have a look at your server logs..

Comment: Your controller doesn't have a return function. Could that be the case. and to be more succint use `Page::find($id)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jquery ajax in laravel you **need to** pass the laravel token in ajax request data!

```
 data: {
           id: 'id', _token: token
 },
```

Two quick tips you don't need to use the meta tags in html and any ajax setup. The only thing that you need to do is that make a variable in your view named for example token **var token = '{{Session::token()}}'** and then pass it in ajax data. Other tip is that instead of using the static url, you can make a variable in your view to your post route var url = '{{Route("name")}}'.

Comment: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...' i have this in the error log at the top

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your request in the controller
Make sure you are using

`use Request`
And then edit your controller code to this format

```
public function SomeFunction(Request $request){


    $id = $request->input('id');

    $i = 1;

    foreach($id as $val) {

        $page = Page::where('id', $val)->first();

        $page->order = $i;
        $page->save();

        $i++;

    }


}
```

Comment: ive updated the function however its not liking the for each... it seems to me its not passing in the data

Comment: `dd($id)` and see what you have

Comment: i cant seem to dd it out as its trough the ajax i tried return dd($id) also

Comment: what you `dd` should be in the console.log of your success function in ajax